# google script email form accept/reject

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I wrote some macro code to send an email to a manager based on form submissions (to be used in a expense/approval process), this is my first project using google forms/spreadsheets so maybe i might be missing something simple, but i looked through 2 tutorials for this and my code matches those where it matters.

the first part, SendEmail, works perfectly and emails the manager provided with the few needed columns needed to make a decision.  as well as 2 links to approve or deny.  these links are built by using the URL generated when i published the code and appending approval=true and the email of the person who submited the form request.

the next part, doGet(e), is supposed to trigger when the link in the manager email is clicked and then generate an email to send to the requester, however, when the link is clicked it just brings me to a page that says "Invalid email: undefined" even though the URL at the top has all the right information.

what am i missing here?

edit: I was using this video to get the layout of most of the code:   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eduG0XZ9mDs

code:

```js
function sendEmail(e){
  /**
 var email = e.values[1];
 var item = e.values[2]; 
 var cost = e.values[3];
  */
  var serviceInformation = e.values[1];
  var language = e.values[2];
  var meetingType = e.values[3];
  var eventDate = e.values[4];
  var clientName = e.values[5];
  var detailedDirections = e.values[6];
  var onSitePOCName = e.values[7];
  var onSitePOCNumber = e.values[8];
  var department = e.values[9];
  var contactPhoneNumber = e.values[10];
  var approval = e.values[11];  //the one we need to modify
  var requestorEmail = e.values[12];
  var managerEmail = e.values[13];
  var Language2 = e.values[14];
  var interpreterName = e.values[15];
  var interpreterAgency = e.values[16];
  var dateConformationSent = e.values[17];
  var specialNotes = e.values[18];
  
  
  var url = 'https://script.google.com/a/macros/richmond.k12.va.us/s/AKfycbwuRr1boKTH0v1mprWmc7PE66_mQ_dmPE0lyWb7vkfiyW3pn31b/exec';
 
  
  /**might be that the & needs to be a ?*/
  var approve = url + '?approval=true'+'?reply='+requestorEmail;
  var reject = url + '?approval=false'+'?reply='+requestorEmail;
  
  var html = "<HTML><body>"+
               "<h2>please review</h2><br />"
  +"<P>" + language +"  " + serviceInformation
  +"<p>" + meetingType+ "  on   "+ eventDate + "    for " +clientName
  +"<p>" + "Location: "+ department
  +"<p>" + "requester: "+ requestorEmail+ "  "+
    "<p>"+
    
    "<a href="+ approve +">Approve</a><br />"+
      "<p>"+
              
    "<a href=" +reject+">Reject</a><br />"+
              "</HTML></body>";
                   

MailApp.sendEmail(managerEmail, "Approval Request", "what no html?", {htmlBody: html});
  
}


function doGet(e) {
 
  
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  
  var aprovalResponce = (e.parameter.approval == 'true') ? 'Approved.' : 'Sorry, you need to reschedule';
  
  var msg = "Your manager said :" + aprovalResponce;
  
  var replyEmail = e.parameter.reply;
Logger.log(replyEmail);
  
  MailApp.sendEmail(replyEmail, "Approval Request", msg);
  
  var helloWorldLabel = app.createLabel(msg);
  app.add(helloWorldLabel);
  

  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

Oh, that video was made before the [UI Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/ui-service) service was deprecated, that's what you're calling on the first line of the doGet(). Google stopped supporting this in favor of a different service, [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) So this doGet() portion may not be workable even if perfectly transcribed from the video.

Comment: I added it to the code above as well as the code I have as the working copy,

Comment: I added it to the code above as well as the code I have as the working copy, it seems like that it is pulling back undefined, but it might be because I am calling it wrong?  from what i can tell it looks like it is running it with no real inputs for e (what is supposed to be the URL link with additional information after the ?'s).
after adding a few more rows to the data using the actual form and getting the first email sent out with the links to approve or deny I clicked on a few of then and then checked the logs in the code and it is still blank.

Comment: using the debugging mode on doGet brings up a "cannot read property "approval" from undefined on this code line(my guess is due to lack of real input):
  var aprovalResponce = (e.parameter.approval == 'true') ? 'Approved.' : 'Sorry, you need to reschedule';

Comment: that was it, got the emails working both ways, just needed to change like 2 lines of code.

Comment: do you happen to know how to update a field in the spreadsheet from my doGet() method?  I think all i would need is for the method to open the data spreadsheet and update the approved field depending on the value passed in from the URL.   I might need to add another identifier like the row number or timestamp into the URL to pick the right one

Comment: I'm not sure what your updated code looks like, but updating a cell in a spreadsheet should be pretty straightforward, can you put that in a new question?  It's hard to do a lot of show and tell in the comments.  Also, if you found the above answer helpful, can you mark it accepted?

Comment: Thanks!  If you give it a go yourself, experiment with the snippets in the Google Scripts documentation for the Sheet and Range Classes, in particular take a look at the getRange(), getValue(), setValue() methods.  That should give you an idea of how to do this.

Comment: [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet), [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)